# MVVM: how to avoid using ObservableCollection in model in a list of lists scenario?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I have a view with an editable (add, modify, remove) list of MyBaseListModel items.
Every individual MyBaseListModel item has itself a member sublist that can be opened with an Expander to show the individual model items. This list can be edited as well.
Two different sublist can be opedend at the same time.

Firs I implemented the ObservableCollections directly in the model:

```
public class MyBaseListModel
{
    ObservableCollection<MyBaseModel> MyBaseList;
    // other members
}
```

And then the VM:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection MyListsfList;

    public MyViewModel(List<MyBaseListModel> l)
    {
        MyListofList = new ObservableCollection(l);
    }
    ....
 }
```

And this works ok.

Then I read that it is not a good custom to implement ObservableCollections directly in the model, and I agree.
So I changed the models to use a List:

```
public class MyBaseListModel
{
    List<MyBaseModel> MyBaseList;
    // other members
}
```

But now I can not edit the sigle sublists because MyListofList[i].MyBaseList is itself a simple List and not an ObservableCollection.

Should I rebuild every single MyBaseListModel item in the view model constructor to replace the List with an ObservableCollection ?

Or should I build in the VM a Collection of ObservableCollection wrappers on the MyBaseList?

Or should I hierarchically compose different ViewModels creating a MyBaseListViewModel that wraps every single MyBaseListModel object using ObservableCollection?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between an `ObservableCollection<T>` and a `List<T>` is that the former implements the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface and raises notifications to the UI when items are added or removed. If you need this, you should use an `ObservableCollection<T>`. If you don't, you might as well use a `List<T>`. Both types implement the `IList<T>` and `ICollection' interfaces and can be modified.

There is nothing wrong with adding an `ObservableCollection<T>` to a class like `MyBaseListModel` provided that this is a client specific type. If `MyBaseListModel` is some kind of domain object that is shared between different projects on both the client and the server side, you should consider to wrap it in a view model, i.e. a "child" view model of `MyViewModel`, on the client side instead of modifying the actual domain object.

It's rarely useful to bind directly to domain, business or data transfer objects in a WPF application. It's generally a better approach to create UI specific wrapper objects and bind to these, at least if you can't use the "original" object as-is for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

ObservableCollection has a constructor which takes in an IEnumerable, so you can just pass in your List.

Dunno who told you that a model shouldn't have ObservableCollection, but they done told you wrong. In fact, it's something that's supported by EF and NHibernate out of the box.

The bigger question is why you'd think its a good idea to have a Model v1 that's not observable and then create an exact clone of that model v2 just to make it observable and then have to keep translating between the two.

In fact, the ONLY time where you shouldn't use the EXACT model objects in your VM is when they need to be repackaged / transformed. And if they need to be repackaged / transformed, you should probably re-think why you didn't build them in that way in the first place.